# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at

Tags: php, header, warning

> {"result":"Success"}
>   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/host1475174/сайт.ru/htdocs/www/auth.php:65) in /home/host1475174/сайт.ru/htdocs/www/auth.php on line 67

После авторизации выдает такую ошибку. Уже 2 часа ищу решение проблемы, перепробовал наверное все.

Строки 65 и 67 из auth.php

```
curl_exec($myCurl);
header('Location: ' . $urlreturn);
```

Comment: Иногда мне кажется, что если в гугл ввести "порно", то он и там выведет меньшее количество совпадений, чем по тексту данной ошибки. Вы вообще пробовали искать?

Comment: Самая самая ссылка на эту тему http://cannot-modify-header-information.ru/

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что HTTP-заголовки должны предшествовать телу HTTP-документа. Так как PHP - интерпретируемый язык, то инструкции в нем выполняются построчно. После того, как вы вывели что-то при помощи инструкций echo или print (в данном случае {"result":"Success"} ), считается что вы начали формировать тело HTTP-документа и заголовки больше отправляться не будут.

Встретив попытку отправить HTTP-заголовок

```
header('Location: ' . $urlreturn);
```

Интерпретатор выводит вам предупреждение.